# Remove all files with specified extension from network share on OS X using Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line-interface, command-prompt

After connecting to a network share on OS X I am looking to delete all files that have a particular extension (filename.exte for example) from all folders within the share. If i'm in the very top folder is there a command in terminal I can run that will do this?

If this it not possible, is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: This is quite a common question. `cd` to where your share is mounted (usually `/Volumes/whatever`) then apply this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/377438/how-can-i-recursively-delete-all-files-of-a-specific-extension-in-the-current-di

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`find`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html):

```
$ find /Volumes/whatever -type f -name \*.exte -exec rm -f {} \;
```

However you need to be very careful - one slip and you could delete a lot of files uninintentionally - I usually do a "dry run" first:

```
$ find /Volumes/whatever -type f -name \*.exte -exec echo "rm -f {}" \;
```

(this will just list the files that would be deleted with the first version, but will not actually delete anything).